# How to pass user id in list view through firebase

Tags: kotlin

My app has a mood journal whereby users are able to fill in data about their mood, upon submission they are taken to another activity where they view their data.I want the users to only be able to see their data. What should i do?

.I have implemented a user id in firebase corresponding with auth as well. Am using kotlin